# Express (Node) - Right way to send error messages through middleware cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

In express applications, what is the right way to send error messages to views ?

(we assume that the code is synchronous)

Example 1 :

```
// Route
Router.route('/')
  .get(controller.getIndex);

// Controller
Controller.getIndex = function (req, res, next) {
  doSomething(function (err, datas) {
    if (err) { res.locals.err = 'error message'; }
    // ...
  });
  res.render(/* view */);
};

// View 
<p class="error">${ out.global.err }</p>
```

Here no problem : if there is an error, I store a message in the response and display it in the view.

Example 2 :

```
// Route (with multiple middlewares)
Router.route('/')
  .get(firstMiddleware, otherMiddleware/*, otherMiddleware2, etc */, controller.getIndex);

// firstMiddleware (always need to be called)
firstMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  doAlsoSomething(function (err, datas) {
    if (err) { res.locals.err = 'error message'; }
    // ...
  });
  next();
};

// otherMiddleware, otherMiddleware2 (need to be called only if no errors)
otherMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  next();
};

// Controller (need to be called only if want to display the view)
Controller.getIndex = function (req, res, next) {
  doSomething(function (err, datas) {
    if (err) { res.locals.err = 'error message'; }
    // ...
  });
  res.render(/* view */);
};

// View 
<p class="error">${ out.global.err }</p>
```

In this example, otherMiddleware will be always called. It is not what I want, it should stop the middlewares cycle in case of errors. Then if errors need to be display on the view it should called `Controller.getIndex()` with error messages like in example 1. If errors have their own views (as 404, 500...), it should not call the `Controller.getIndex()`, but the appropriate view. In any cases, if an error occurs in otherMiddlewareX, the middlewares "after" (otherMiddlewareX + 1, otherMiddlewareX + 2 ... otherMiddlewareN) should not be called.

Anyone can help me to find a "right" way to do that ?

EDIT : [similar problem](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/1662) [similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840545/is-it-possible-to-skip-route-middleware-in-node-express)

**Possible answers** (i can give example of implementations if necessary) :

- Put a condition `if (res.locals.err)` in each middleware to jump to the next one in case of errors by calling `next();`. That's not very convenient.
- Call an error-handling middleware with `next('error message');` but it is hard to manage every redirection in one function (this is the solution i use)
- Use `next('route');` with a **route duplication each time** to manage error (similar as error-handling middleware solution).
- Use `res.redirect();` and flash messages (session, query string, db, cookie...). If I use this solution, I need to make it stateless. I could do it with query string for example, but this is also not very convenient to me. Furthermore, it doesn't really answer the question directly but more the question [how to pass message between requests in REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924247/pass-messages-between-requests-with-a-rest-api-json-xml-html).

There is probably a way to do that easily with express app, but I can't arrive to figure out what's the right way. Could you please help me ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : More details about possible answers (third solution).

With `next('error message');` I have an error-handler middleware where I need to display the good view. The view can be a 500, 404, 406... but also a 200 with an error message on it. Firstly, I need to give the status code to this middleware, then if it's a 200 I need to call the view that corresponds to the error. The problem is that I don't always know which view to call. I can have a POST on /auth that needs to be redirected to GET /login. I need to "hardcode" it and can't write the same code for every situations or i need to pass the view/controller in each `next('error message');` call. Even the redirection is hard, because sometimes I need to call a controller, but sometimes I needs to go through another middleware cycle by calling the route, not the controller and the only way I found is `return app._router.handle(req, res, next);` which looks more as a "hack" that an official solution. If i redirect with res.redirect(); i came back to my second possible answer where i need to pass some flash messages. To finish, this is the solution i use (`next(err)`), but i was hoping for a better way.

Comment: On your third suggestion, what do you mean by "but it is hard to manage every redirection in one function"?

Comment: I mean that i have a lot of different cases to manage and it's hard for me to find a solution which works for every situations without "hardcode" it. 
I will give more details in my post.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood your whole problem but I would use and error handling middleware like this:

```js
// firstMiddleware
var firstMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  doAlsoSomething(function (err, datas) {
    if (err) { next('error message'); }
    // ...
    next(); // If err is true calls renderView
  });
};

// otherMiddleware
var otherMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  // Do stuff only if no error
  next();
};

// Controller
Controller.getIndex = function (req, res, next) {
  doSomething(function (err, datas) {
    if (err) { next('error message'); }
    // ...
    next(); // If err is true calls renderView
  });
};

// This middleware runs after next('error message')
var handleError = function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.err = err.message;
}

// This middleware always runs
var renderView = function (req, res, next) {
  res.render(/* view */);
}

// Route
Router.route('/')
  .get(firstMiddleware, otherMiddleware/*, otherMiddleware2, etc */, controller.getIndex, handleError, renderView);
```

Comment: That's one solution, thank you. The thing annoying with this solution is that i need to put the `handleError` in each route.

Comment: I updated the answer to support async callbacks in `doAlsoSomething` and `doSomething`. For some reason I forgot to assume they were async. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using `otherMiddleware` once, get rid of it, then move its content to the `else` block of the previous middleware:

```js
var checkForm = function (req, res, next) {
  validationResult(function (err, datas) {
    if (err) { res.locals.err = 'error message'; }
    else {
      // Do stuff only if form is valid
      // otherMiddleware code
    }
    // ...
  });
  next();
};
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer.
I am not using `otherMiddleware` only in this situation. It is used in others middlewares cycles. In fact, as you can see in my examples, you even can have few middlewares. You can totally have : `.get(checkForm, otherMiddleware1, otherMiddleware2, otherMiddleware3, otherMiddleware4, otherMiddleware5, controller.getIndex)` with each middleware doing different things and which can be used in other routes. `checkForm` is just an example, but you can replace it by `otherMiddleware0` if you want ;)