# Pass messages between requests with a REST API (JSON, XML, HTML...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

Let's imagine a REST API that can return JSON, XML, HTML and other formats.
In case of a browser web client without JavaScript enabled, the API return HTML. Tokens are used for authentication and authorization.

In a *classic website project*, it can happen that a **redirection** need to be made from a page A to another page B. It can be used for example to display a welcome message or an error message in another page. In this case, to display a message (flash for example) from page A on the page B, we would normally use session. Two simple (and minify) examples in express (but the concept is the same in other technologies):

```
// With session directly
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({ /* ... */ });

function (req, res, next) {
  req.session.message = 'Welcome, you are connected';
  return res.redirect('/');
}

<p class="message">${ session.message }</p>

// With a library as connect-flash
const flash = require('connect-flash');

app.use(flash());

function (req, res, next) {
  req.flash('error', {
    message: 'An error!',
  });
  return res.redirect('/login');
}

<p class="message">${ flash.message }</p>
```

Now, based on REST principles, to respect the stateless constraints, it should not use sessions which store a state between two requests.

My question is : **How a stateless web server should normally pass messages between two requests ?** (in case of a redirection)

- Session : Not stateless as required
- DB ?
- Query string ?
- Cookie ?
- Other ?

Note : I know how implement these solutions but i am asking for a *right way* to do that in the case of a stateless web server. How normally REST API implement it ?

Following this question, I have two (optionnal) misunderstandings.

Based on [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3105337/3614478) :

> That does not preclude other services that the web server talks to
>   from maintaining state about business objects such as shopping carts,
>   just not about the client's current application/session state.

What does **other services** means here ?

Based on [this comment from the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions/3105337#comment36934411_3105337) :

> The authentication can be implicit in the state, do you think that
>   facebook does a "database access" on every request of its REST API? Or
>   Google for that matter? hint: no

What does it means by **implicit in the state** ? If it is that they use token or a similar authentication process, then they should make a database access each time to get a fresh user, no ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Other Service` could be Redis or any NoSQL database that could store a user state between API calls. See `backed service` definition from [12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/backing-services).

Comment: Could we summarize by any process, other than the web server, which can store data ?

Comment: Yes, it could be any shared resource that can store data.

Comment: What do you mean by resource in your last sentence ?

Comment: Something that could be consumed by your app: another web service, database. file or even a process (in case we work on one single machine).